# Activity Recognition Api wrongly detecting inVehicle

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-play-services, intentservice, activity-recognition

Sometimes when a user is sitting, or the phone is still on a table. the if statement which checks if inVehicle & 100% is triggered and the service in my app is started. I cannot figure out why ?

**Activity Recognition in MainActivity**

```
public String getDetectedActivity(int detectedActivityType) {
    Resources resources = this.getResources();
    switch (detectedActivityType) {
        case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
            return resources.getString(R.string.in_vehicle);
        case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
            return resources.getString(R.string.on_bicycle);
        case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
            return resources.getString(R.string.on_foot);
        case DetectedActivity.RUNNING:
            return resources.getString(R.string.running);
        case DetectedActivity.WALKING:
            return resources.getString(R.string.walking);
        case DetectedActivity.STILL:
            return resources.getString(R.string.still);
        case DetectedActivity.TILTING:
            return resources.getString(R.string.tilting);
        case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN:
            return resources.getString(R.string.unknown);
        default:
            return resources.getString(R.string.unidentifiable_activity, detectedActivityType);
    }
}


public void requestActivityUpdates() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GoogleApiClient not yet connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("acr", true);
        editor.commit();

        ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 100, getActivityDetectionPendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
    }

}

public void removeActivityUpdates() {
    ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.removeActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, getActivityDetectionPendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
}

private PendingIntent getActivityDetectionPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivitiesIntentService.class);

    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 20, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public void onResult(Status status) {
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Successfully added activity detection.");

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + status.getStatusMessage());
    }
}


public class ActivityDetectionBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ArrayList<DetectedActivity> detectedActivities = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.STRING_EXTRA);
        String activityString = "";
        for (DetectedActivity activity : detectedActivities) {
            activityString += "Activity: " + getDetectedActivity(activity.getType()) + ", Confidence: " + activity.getConfidence() + "%\n";
        }
        //mDetectedActivityTextView.setText(activityString);
        //Toast.makeText(context, activityString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG2, activityString);

        final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        detectEnabled = preferences.getBoolean("mode", false);
        buttonToggleDetect.setBackground(ui.uiToggle(getApplicationContext(), detectEnabled));


    }
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}
```

**Intent Service**

```
 public class ActivitiesIntentService extends IntentService {

    // TODO REMOVE EXPORTED & ENABLED IN MANIFEST RELATED TO THIS CLASS

    private static final String TAG = "ActivitiesIntentService";


    public ActivitiesIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        boolean serviceState;
        int inVehicle = 0;
        int onFoot = 2;
        int walking = 7;
        int running = 8;
        int tilting = 5;
        int still = 3;


        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, CallDetectService.class); //creating a new intent to be sent to CallDetectService class

        ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
        Intent i = new Intent(Constants.STRING_ACTION);

        ArrayList<DetectedActivity> detectedActivities = (ArrayList) result.getProbableActivities();

        // Log each activity.
        Log.i(TAG, "activities detected");
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        serviceState = preferences.getBoolean("mode", false);

        for (DetectedActivity da : detectedActivities) {


            // // TODO: 16/07/16 local  invehicle int precentage, if int is <50  return
            // todo set up for logs from past day to be sent by user

            if (da.getType() == inVehicle && da.getConfidence() >= 100 ) {


                if (!serviceState) {
                    /*
                    ComponentName service = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), CallDetectService.class);
                    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(service,
                            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                    */

                    Log.d("Service", "service enabled by acr");


                    startService(serviceIntent);
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.music_marimba_chord);

                    mp.start();
                    //TODO ADD MP.FINISH HERE
                }

            }

            //else if (da.getType() == still  && da.getConfidence() >= 25)

            else if  (da.getType() == onFoot && da.getConfidence() >= 25
                    || da.getType() == walking && da.getConfidence() >= 25
                    || da.getType() == running && da.getConfidence() >= 25
                    || da.getType() == still && da.getConfidence() == 100)

            {
                // stop detect service
                if (serviceState) {
                    stopService(serviceIntent);

                    /*ComponentName service = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), CallDetectService.class);
                    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(service,
                            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                    */

                    Log.d("Service", "service disabled by acr");


                }
            }

        }


        i.putExtra(Constants.STRING_EXTRA, detectedActivities);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);

    }
}
```

Am I missing something? I really cant figure it out.
I tried putting in a component enabled/disabled setting in the intent service which is commented. when I had that in the code, the service did not start when the user was not inVehicle but when turn on and off when they actually where.
Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It could be the device's sensors having a lot of noise during the updates.  Nexus 6, HTC phones, and a few Motorola phones I've tested on have been notorious about this.  If I remember correctly, the confidence levels given by all the detected activities are independent, so even though IN_VEHICLE has 100, STILL could have a slightly lower confidence.  If that's the case, I'd put some logic to verify the user is indeed IN_VEHICLE.